# prevent unwanted search terms in magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, advanced-search, search-criteria, search-terms

I having some issue with some search term which shows the result with unwanted scripts.

So how can I prevent the search term so that it does not show unwanted results?

May anyone help me?